# For loop running infinite python

Tags: python

It's been 5 hours trying to find the issue but unable to identify why for loop `for fn in L` running  infinite.

```
L=[]
N=int(raw_input())
for i in range(0,N):
    L.append(list(raw_input().split()))
print L

for fn in L:
    if 'insert'==fn[0]:
        L.insert(int(fn[1]),int(fn[2]))
    elif 'append'==fn[0]:
        L.append(int(fn[1]))
    elif 'remove'==fn[0]:
        L.remove(int(fn[1]))
    elif 'pop'==fn[0]:
        L.pop(int(fn[1]))
    elif 'index'==fn[0]:
        L.index(int(fn[1])) 
    elif 'count'==fn[0]:
        L.count(int(fn[1]))
    elif 'sort'==fn[0]:
        L.sort()     
    elif 'reverse'==fn[0]:
        L.reverse() 
    else :
        print  L
```

Inputs provided to list:

```
12
insert 0 5
insert 1 10
insert 0 6
print 
remove 6
append 9
append 1
sort 
print
pop
reverse
print
```

Comment: What input are you giving it?

Comment: @mgilson: added input in question

Comment: Which for loop inside the for loop? I see two not nested explicit for loops.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're *mutating* your list in the loop. Outcomes will be very unpredictable. You can instead iterate on a slice of the list:

```
for fn in L[:]:
    # your code here
    pass
```

In this way, the loop terminates when the items in the shallow copy (the slice) are exhausted.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What is slice of list?

Comment: It s a shortcut, a slice ([:]) without bound, so a copy of the list as slicing a list create a new list. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation

Comment: @Code-Monk In this context: a temporary shallow copy of the original list. Read more [here](https://ramisayar.com/hidden-features-in-python-slicing-and-sliding/)

Answer (score 2):

You insert/remove elements while iterating the elements of a list. You also change the list by reversing the list. Both are mutation operations to the list which are not allowed during iteration. The behavior is unspecified in this case.

```
for fn in L:
    if ...:
        L.insert(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

You mutate the object used for looping ... and better you reverse it :p reverse <-- reverse --> reverse <-- reverse -->

:p